# rsync back error 23 on Thunderbird file

Tags: 16.04, backup, email, thunderbird, rsync

This is for ubuntu 16.04

I'm running grsync on my laptop directories for TB and others. Destination directory is on a WD MyBook NAS.

I've experienced no problems using TB, but the following rsync error for one of the folders/files makes me wonder whether my backup is good:

**rsync: delete_file: unlink(.thunderbird/5lcp3bku.default/Mail/Local Folders/1 Kids.sbd/.K Renee.G5xJwY) failed: Device or resource busy (16)**

**rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.1]**

**Rsync process exit status: 23**

The grsync log showed:

**** Launching RSYNC command:**

**rsync -r -t -p -o -g -v --progress --delete -u -l -H -s [source] [dest]**

**sending incremental file list**

**deleting .thunderbird/5lcp3bku.default/Mail/Local Folders/1 Kids.sbd/K Renee.msf**

**rsync: delete_file: unlink(.thunderbird/5lcp3bku.default/Mail/Local Folders/1 Kids.sbd/.K Renee.G5xJwY) failed: Device or resource busy (16)**

**deleting .thunderbird/5lcp3bku.default/Mail/Local Folders/1 Kids.sbd/K Renee**

**.thunderbird/**

**.thunderbird/5lcp3bku.default/**

[and so forth]

It's always the same file.  Today I created a new TB folder ('K Renee 2'), moved all the messages from 'K Renee' into it, and deleted the original 'K Renee'.  I thought that might clear it up, but I still get the same message.

At the terminal on my laptop (source machine), I can walk to the parent source directory, and I can see that the original 'K Renee' is gone and the new one is there.
[image: source directory]

When I walk to the destination drive using Nautilus (don't know how to get there at the terminal), the directories and files are the same.
[image: destination directory]

Why is this still targeting the same file?  I don't see it in either location.

I also don't understand why the TB folder for 'K Jon' is the only one that has an *.sbd directory.

Can anyone shed light?

Comment: `perror 16;perror 23` might help you investigate.

Comment: Sorry, not a programmer.  I don't know how to use that.  From the command line, it lists 4 packages that include perror, but they don't include rsync or grsync.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working normally, though I don't know exactly how.

In TB, I moved all messages from the problem email folder into a new one, then I deleted the old one.

I ran grsync once or twice and got the same result.  But eventually the linux gods smiled on me and I don't get the error any more.